# ceiling fan not getting enough power

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, installation

not enough power to my new ceiling fan
Connected new ceiling fan as directed and it starts to turn and then stops.
Old fan worked great but did not have lights. The new one has led lights and remote.
Suggestions?

Comment: 1 - Does it stop by tripping a breaker? Or stop and if you flip the switch off/on it starts again? 2 - Model # of fan? 3 - Do the light work?

Comment: 1-doesnt trip breaker 2- model #Slinger V2 #LP8147SLBN

Comment: 3-Lights work 4-NOTE-Remote turns on lights, fans turn one way, stop and turn other way then the blades stop turning ????

Comment: I doubt your problem is “not enough power”, more likely defective fan or remote receiver.

Comment: I took a look at your fan part number. You are only pulling 35W on the fan and 18W on the LED light kit, so you should be getting plenty of power. Check the voltage at the box and see if you are getting 120V. Your fan may have been going through a check system before working. You might try the remote again. If nothing else try their service department number 1-888-567-2055 and see what they have to say. FYI today is a holiday I would try them tomorrow 8 a.m.-5 p.m., EST, Monday-Friday. Sorry I can't be of anymore help.

Comment: It would be possible to have the light and fan wires switched on the wireless receiver in the fan shroud. Does the light button on the remote have a dimmer function? If so, is the dimmer function working properly? On our Hunter one presses and holds the light button to dim or brighten the light.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

1. Does the fan have a pull chain switch? If so, you may have the pull chain switch on the fan in low. Pull chain switch must be in high for remote to function. Push high fan on the remote and then go through the settings with the pull chain to get to high fan.
2. Does the fan have a reverse switch? Make sure the reverse switch is not activated.
3. Is there a wall switch? Is it a dimmer switch? If so, it my be in a dimmed state.
4. Fan may be defective.